# Latest ubuntu sees no disks at all

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, software-installation, 22.04

I have used 18.04 lts before with pleasure but now on a new machine 22.04.1 LTS will not install. It does not see a pre formatted (ext4) 500 gb ssd partition and also not the other 4tb disks, which might be logic as they are NTFS. Main concern is the ext4. Could it be due to the fact that W11 is on the other part of the ssd? That would be stupid no? I tried gparted and disks, but on neither of them visibility, nor via terminal, I only see the thumbdrive with the image. Anyone?

Comment: You mention the latest Ubuntu (2022-October or 22.10) in the title, but then mention an six month older release of Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (2022-April release), so please be clear & specific.  If windows is not *cleanly* shutdown, other OSes will not touch it as it'll cause data loss (ie. system is hibernated, or has fastboot enabled [which resumes from a prepared hibernate file & doesn't actually coldboot!]).  I'd suggest you clarify your question

Comment: Apologies, the image is ubuntu-22.04.1 desktop. The machine is booted directly from the iso, windows is not active and on another partition. Oh, btw, are you saying I should disable fastboot in the bios? Or set it to standard?

Comment: Please correct your question then, it still talks of *latest* (ie. 22.10 or the 2022-October release) but only mentions 22.04 & 18.04 or older LTS systems.  Comments are intended for readers to query the OP or *Original Poster*, and will get removed once dealt with via additional details, or clarifications to the question; which is still unclear.  Answers are to the question itself (*not readers comments*).  A *unclean* windows partition (ie. *fastboot* or *hibernate* enabled) can cause that partition table to be ignored; so if its a single drive; put windows in a *clean* state.

Comment: Fast boot is an UEFI setting that assumes you have made no system changes and immediately loads system using data previously written to drive from last full boot or cold boot. Fast start up is a Windows setting that sets hibernation flag. Linux will not normally mount hibernated NTFS to prevent damage. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: Sure, you mentioned fastboot in your comment hence my question, all good. I simply do not understand why install halts at the point where one picks a drive/partition to use And sees nothing where there are 4.....